# Will hats be seen in the list of participants in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, winter-bash

I see Winter Bash is live again (woo!)

I do see hats being added to the message composition bar and to each of my messages, but I don't see them appearing in the list of participants for a channel. Is this a bug or a feature request?

[image: Hats aren't consistent]

Or does it take too many resources or time to generate so many hats (e.g. when looking at a list of participants under "all rooms")?

Answer (score 4):

They will be shown in the message list on the left; it could be that the other participants don't wear any hats yet. Here is a screenshot from a [chatroom with some hats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), like Waffles, the Top(bar) Hat and Clean-up Duty:

[image]

They're not shown in the grid; since it's possible to wear hats 'outside' your avatar, that would get *very* messy; some user's hats would surely cover other user's avatars, especially when there are multiple rows with users:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing in the screenshot I included in my question above (hats appear for some participants in the room).  Are you saying that hats will never appear for participants listed in the room grid, along the right side?

Comment: They won't, it'd get too messy in full rooms.

Comment: I love hat :D .

Comment: I didn't even know there was a chat!